# Error handling inside of classes

Tags: c++, class, error-handling

Say I have this code inside of a class constructor:

```
if(SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    std::cerr << "Couldn't init SDL2 video" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
}
```

How could I use try, throw, catch to handle errors instead of if, cerr? Should I use a member function that checks for errors (return bool), then use try, throw, catch for error handling?

Constructor:

```
GLWindow::GLWindow(int width, int height, std::string name) {
    // Init SDL Video
    if(SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    std::cerr << "Couldn't init SDL2 video" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    // Forward compatibility
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);

    // Main window
    glWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(name.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    // Check if Main window is created
    if(glWindow == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't create main window" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    // GL Context for Main Window
    glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(glWindow);

    // Check if GL Context is created
    if(glContext == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't create GL context for main window" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use exceptions for general flow control, they are for _exceptional_ situations. I don't see how their use would be considered reasonable here unless you are in a constructor. Just return a success/fail value.

Comment: This is in a constructor, that's why I'm having problems with it

Comment: Then you should _edit_ your post and include that information there. i suggest adding an example constructor and how it's being used to make it clear.

Comment: I'm trying to quit the program if there is an error. Someone told me I could do this through exception handling in main() (which is where the objects are made) but I'm new to exception handling and it seems a bit harder from within classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
try {
    if (SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't init 2D video");
    }
}

catch(const std::runtime_error &e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment:

> *"I'm trying to quit the program if there is an error. Someone told me I could do this through exception handling in main() (which is where
>   the objects are made) but I'm new to exception handling and it seems a
>   bit harder from within classes."*

I would say that you could make a call to `std::terminate()` which will quit your program.

For example:

```
#include<exception>//std::terminate() 
//the rest of your code 

//...
if(glContext == NULL) {
    std::cerr << "Couldn't create GL context for main window" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    std::terminate();//exit program on error
    //you don't have to get rid of the std::cerr calls if you don't want to 
    //because in theory you could rout them to the terminal or some error log
    //that you could use for debugging or error logging purposes
}
//...
```

Though I believe that doing this is most likely not the best way to handle the errors. The answer from Andreas DM would be a good start in the right direction I believe.

Take a look at this article for some info on exceptions:
[https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#ctor-exceptions](http://Take%20a%20look%20at%20this%20article)